# System.ObjectDisposedException when I don't wait a few seconds

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-5

I have a repository that return a list of entities. the code is the following:

```
public List<MainEntities> getAllEntitiesOfType()
        {
            try
            {
                using (catalogoEntitiesSQLiteEF5 miDBContext = new catalogoEntitiesSQLiteEF5())
                    {
                        miDBContext.RelatedEntities.SqlQuery("Select * from RelatedEntities").ToList<RelatedEntities>();
                        miDBContext.MainEntities.SqlQuery("Select * from MainEntities where IDMainEntity IN(" + convertIDToString(miDBContext.RelatedEntities.Select(v => v.IDMainEntity).ToList<long>()) + ")").ToList<MainEntities>();

                        return miDBContext.MainEntities.Local.ToList<MainEntites>();
                    }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
}
```

The returned list is used in the main application to populate the list that is used as itemSource of the dataGrid.

However, I get the exception System.ObjectDisposedException.

If I use a break point in the return of the method of the repository and wait a few seconds, I don't get this error, but if I don't put this break point then I get the exception.

It seems that has relation with entities without connection because I close the dataContext, but I don't know well.

I am using SQLite with EF5 in an .net 4.0 application.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to `JOIN` all the dependent tables in your SQL query in order to eagerly fetch all the data and populate the entire object hierarchy. This way, they won't be lazily loaded when you attempt to access them outside of the DbContext.

Comment: Thanks, I disabled lazy loading and it works fine.

Comment: Great, I have posted this as an answer.

Comment: the try/catch here is pointless.  If you do nothing but rethrow exceptions, why bother catching them?

Comment: the exception is thrown to the main application, that show a message to the user. are There other ways to notify to the main application the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable lazy loading in the configuration of your EF or perform the necessary `JOIN` statements to ensure that all the data is eagerly loaded.

```
ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```